# Which banner plugin is this?

Tags: plugins, sidebar

Which plugin is the main banner on this demo website ?

I've wasted much time looking for it. I just couldn't find it.

http://template-demo.org/woo/WCM01/WCM010013/WP1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be revslider

http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380

Warning, last year there was some information about it having a vulnerability on wordpress websites. The 2 websites I had it pre installed on via themes have also broken due to a update in rev slider requiring me to go in and amend the rev slider code to disable it. I was unable to get in the admin section otherwise.